# Fast element-wise division of matrix, generated from vector with `Outer`, and another matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, list-manipulation

```
m = {a, b, c};
n = {{e, r, t}, {y, u, i}, {g, h, j}};
k = Outer[Divide, m, m];
k/n
```

gives

```
{{1/e, a/(b r), a/(c t)}, {b/(a y), 1/u, b/(c i)}, {c/(a g), c/(b h), 
  1/j}}
```

I want to do this with very large matrices filled with numbers of arbitrary precision. Is there a faster way?

**EDIT**

The sizes I am looking at for my practical applications start at 20000 and 20000^2 for the vector and matrix, respectively (of course the examples don't have to be with that many).

I am also interested in any method that might parallelise well.

Comment: What is the length of `m` in practical use?

Comment: You can try `m/(n ConstantArray[m, Length[m]])` and see how fast it is.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I editted my question to include some information on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
m = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2000}];
n = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2000, 2000}];
a = Outer[Divide, m, m]/n; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = Map[#/m &, MapThread[#1 #2 &, {m, 1/n}]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
c = m /(ConstantArray[m, Length[m]] n); // RepeatedTiming // First
d = KroneckerProduct[m, 1./m]/n; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b == c == d
```

> 0.958
>
> 0.128
>
> 0.0281
>
> 0.0236
>
> True

## Edit

A parallelized version

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real, 1}, {z, _Real, 1}},
   x/(y z),
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
e = cf[m, n, m]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == e
```

> 0.0096
>
> True

Timing has been measured on a Quad Core CPU which shows that this does not scale too well. Btw., the timing with `CompilationTarget -> "C"` is only 4% slower, so there is always no point to compile it into a library.

Comment: I was just typing a comparison of the answers so far, but you were first. I wouldn't've expected that `KroneckerProduct` would be that quick. Any ideas on any way that might parallelise well? I will edit my question to include that as well.

Comment: See my edit for a parallelized version.

Comment: I am using arbitrary precision numbers, so I guess 'Compile' is not really an option.

Comment: Also, interestingly, but on my machine, with Mathematica 11.3, `a` is faster than `b` though still slower than the other two.

Comment: Yeah, I was also surprised that `a` was _so_ slow on my machine. I don't know what to think about it...

Comment: `Outer` is meant to be parallelisable, as far as I remember. That is why I started with it. However wrapping it with `Parallelize` doesn't do anything. That might be due to my arbitrary precision though, haven't checked with machine, and I can't access a PC now

Answer (score 4):

Pretty printing your result gives...

```
{{1/e, a/(b r), a/(c t)}, {b/(a y), 1/u, b/(c i)}, {c/(a g), c/(b h),1/j}}//MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{e} & \frac{a}{b r} & \frac{a}{c t} \\
 \frac{b}{a y} & \frac{1}{u} & \frac{b}{c i} \\
 \frac{c}{a g} & \frac{c}{b h} & \frac{1}{j} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Try this, it avoids constructing the huge Outer[ ] matrix

```
Map[#/m &, MapThread[#1 #2 &, {m, 1/n}]] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{e} & \frac{a}{b r} & \frac{a}{c t} \\
 \frac{b}{a y} & \frac{1}{u} & \frac{b}{c i} \\
 \frac{c}{a g} & \frac{c}{b h} & \frac{1}{j} \\
\end{array}
\right)$